# Matching a value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to collect data from a table

Table 1 is a flavour picked by the user.

**Table 1**

```
|  T1C1 |   T1C2  | 
-------------------
|    A |  Vanilla |
```

Table 2 is a section of flavours.

**Table 2**

```
|  T2C1 |   T2C2  |  
-------------------
|  1   |Strawberry|
|  2   |Chocolate |
|  3   | Mint     |
|  4   |Strawberry|
|  5   |Chocolate |
|  6   |  Vanilla |
|  7   |Chocolate |
|  8   | Mint     |
|  9   |Chocolate |
```

I wanted to achieve the following result when the chosen flavour has been selected then a '**1**' is assigned to it otherwise it is marked as '**0**'.

**Result**

```
|  T2C1 |   T2C2  | SELECTED|
----------------------------|
|  1   |Strawberry|    0    |
|  2   |Chocolate |    0    |
|  3   | Mint     |    0    |
|  4   |Strawberry|    0    |
|  5   |Chocolate |    0    |
|  6   |  Vanilla |    1    |
|  7   |Chocolate |    0    |
|  8   | Mint     |    0    |
|  9   |Chocolate |    0    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the result.

Here it is if anyone else is interested:

```
SELECT T2C1, T2C2,
CASE WHEN T2C2 = (SELECT T1C2 FROM T1 WHERE (T1C1 = 'A') THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS SELECTED
FROM T2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with a `LEFT JOIN` and check for a null value (no match) in the right-hand table:

```
SELECT 
    T2C1, 
    T2C2, 
    CASE WHEN T1.T1C2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END SELECTED
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 
    ON T2.T2C2 = T1.T1C2
```